# need help in autolayout top layout guide, UIscrollView, UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, parallax

I am working on a top sticked streach header.
My setup:

```
UIScrollView
    -UIView(a container)
       -UIImageView
       -UIView(subContent view)
```

What i want:

Stick `UIImageView` to top layout guide.

`UIImageView` height is 100 - 250. That is `UIImageView` height is initialise with 250, but can not be less than 100.

0 top space in between `UIImageView` and `subContentView`.

So when user scroll towards bottom, `UIImageView` will gradually minimise and will no more minimise as soon as it's height reaches 100(minimum height).

BUT `subContentView` must not overlap my `UIImageView` and be able to scroll till end (accurate content size/ offset)

**What i am able to do is:**

i am able to stick `UIImageView` to `top` based on `layout` `guide`.

I am also able to acheive `height` `range` of `UIImageView` on `scroll` top or bottom (increase and decrease height).

**BUT i am not able to stop UIImageView from being overlapping by my subContentView.**
That is when i scroll to bottom my UIImageView remains stick to top and gradually decreases it's size, at the moment it reaches to height 100,(i am still `scrolling` bottom) my `subContentView` starts overlapping my `UIImageVIew`.

How ever it makes sense as i have no set `constraints` from `top` `layout` guide to `subcontent` `view`.

some thing like:

```
format = @"V:|[topGuide]-**some dynamic value based on UIImageViewHeight**-[subContentView]";
```

How do i achieve this.
Please help me i am working on it from a day, and finally i decided to ask.

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.navigationItem.title = @"Programmatically";

NSMutableDictionary* views = [NSMutableDictionary new];
views[@"super"] = self.view;
views[@"topGuide"] = self.topLayoutGuide; // The bottom of the navigation bar, if a navigation bar is visible. The bottom of the status bar, if only a status bar is visible .. etc...


//Create the ScrollView
UIScrollView* scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //we are using auto layout
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
views[@"scrollView"] = scrollView;

//Create the scrollview contentview
UIView* contentView = [UIView new];
[contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //we are using auto layout
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
views[@"contentView"] = contentView;

//Add the image view and other addtional views to the content view
topImageView = [[WAPlayerDetailHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero andImage:nil];
topImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //we are using auto layout
topImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
topImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[contentView addSubview:topImageView];
views[@"topImageView"] = topImageView;




//Add other content to the scrollable view
UIView* subContentView = [UIView new];
[subContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
subContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //we are using auto layout
[contentView addSubview:subContentView];
views[@"subContentView"] = subContentView;


//Now Let's do the layout
NSArray* constraints;
NSString* format;
NSDictionary* metrics = @{@"imageHeight" : @250.0};

//======== ScrollView should take all available space ========

format = @"|-0-[scrollView]-0-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

format = @"V:[topGuide]-0-[scrollView]-0-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];



//======== ScrollView Content should tie to all four edges of the scrollview ========

format = @"|-0-[contentView]-0-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[scrollView addConstraints:constraints];

format = @"V:|-0-[contentView]-0-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[scrollView addConstraints:constraints];



// ========== Layout the image horizontally

format = @"|-0-[topImageView(==super)]-0-|"; // with trick to force content width
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];



// ========== Put the sub view height, and leave room for image

format = @"|-0-[subContentView]-0-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[scrollView addConstraints:constraints];


// we leave some space between the top for the image view
format = @"V:|-imageHeight-[subContentView(1000)]-0-|"; /*the view height is set to 700 for the example in order to have enough content */
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[scrollView addConstraints:constraints];



// Start of the magic

format = @"V:[topImageView]-0-[subContentView]"; // image view bottom is subcontent top
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[contentView addConstraints:constraints];

// image view top is the top layout

format = @"V:|[topGuide]-0-[topImageView(>=100)]";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];


//Optional stuff, Add The A view
aView = [[WAPlayerDetailHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero andImage:nil];
[aView setAlpha:1.0];
aView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //we are using auto layout
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.79 green:0.9 blue:0.69 alpha:1];
[subContentView addSubview:aView];
views[@"aView"] = aView;

format = @"|[aView]|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[subContentView addConstraints:constraints];

format = @"V:|-[aView(127)]-5-|";
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[subContentView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

this is what happening [video demo](https://drive.google.com/a/kiwitech.com/file/d/0B11S1EUsLRa7cXRMMURPSEl6T28/view?usp=sharing)
i am following this code from [this location](https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/ScrollviewParallax)
i have upload on git [download and you can see](https://github.com/alok1upadhyay/ScrollviewParallax-master-with-circle-updated)

Comment: OMG i cant beleive so much dumb on my side. just add subContentView before UIImageView. So much stupid of me